# Verifying that a program on chain is really running the code claimed

Tags: build-bpf

let's say I have been sent a link to a git repo that the owner says contains the code that a particular program is running.  I can pull the repo and compile the program,  but do any tools exist that let me compare that compiled program to the one at a particular address on chain?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could get the executable data of the program and compare the hashes to what you built yourself.

This progam
https://explorer.solana.com/address/F3qQ9mJep9hwCkJRtRSUcxov5etdRvQU9NBFpPjh4LKo
has this executable data for example
https://explorer.solana.com/address/6B3eh8vqDUhV3JrxW1p1KwxfYiUy4aBSM3qUQ3rE8NM8

Sadly its not exactly the same as the .so file. But you could deploy it to devnet for example and then see it the binaries are the same.

Comment: Ok, so if you wanted to do this in an automated way, you would need to do the following:

1) clone the repo, compile and push to devnet

2) get the data from the original program, and the program just pushed

3) just see if they equal one another?


Out of interest, what is different between the thing on chain and the .so? just some meta data or something the blockchain adds?

Comment: Puh, yeah sounds quite complicated. Maybe someone has a better idea. Sadly I also don't know what the difference between .so and on chain data is. I just compared the on chain data and so file from one of my programs. If you only want to see if the program changed you could hash the binary and then check from time to time if it changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform verification using the anchor build tools.  The general steps go:

- check out the repo at the release tag
- perform verification, ie:

```
anchor verify -p <lib-name> <program-id>
```

If everything goes well, you'll see the output:

```
Build success
<program-id> is verified.
```

Note that this only works for programs that were verifiably built.

More info at https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/verifiable-builds